# Generic collection as parameters

Tags: powershell, generics

I would like to use a generic collection as a parameter type for a PowerShell function like so:

```
function Execute-Tokenlist
{
    param([System.Collections.Generic.List[WTToken]]$Tokenlist)

}
```

[WTToken] is just a custom type.

I create a new generic collection list with WTToken objects:

```
$TokenList1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[WTToken]
```

But when I try to call the function

```
Execute-Tokenlist -Tokenlist $TokenList1
```

the result is a ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException because PowerShell turns System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WTToken] into a new type:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WTToken, TokenListeAuswerten.ps1, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

So it adds the script name as an assembly name to the type name.

My question is: How can I prevent that PowerShell does these kind of type transformation?

I know I could use Object as a parameter type but I don't like giving up type checking for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and (of course) it has a simple explanation.

Powershell includes in the full name of any type thats based on a class definition the path of the Ps1 file that contains the class definition or just "\powershell" if the definition is not in a ps1 file.

My mistake was that I was opening a new script window inside the ISE and put in the code for defining the class.

Then I tried to put an object based on that class in a generic collection that was already defined inside a ps1 file and has an Add method that excpects objects with a type that includes a ps1 file. Since the new object type name didn't contain that ps1 path I got that error messages that didn't make sense to me (now it does).

Here is the complete PowerShell script code again:

```
class WTToken
{
    [String]$Type
    [String]$Name
    [Bool]$Value
}

$TokenList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[WTToken]]::new()

$Token = [WTToken]::new()
$TokenList.Add($Token)
$TokenList.GetType().FullName
```

Start the ISE, paste in that code and save it into a ps1 file, eg. test.ps1 and run it with F5.

Now open a new script window and paste in the following Powershell code:

```
class WTToken
{
    [String]$Type
    [String]$Name
    [Bool]$Value
}

$Token = [WTToken]::new()
$TokenList.Add($Token)
```

Run this and an error message should appear.